# iTunes stucking on “installing” when installing .ipa files

Tags: iphone, itunes

i have downloaded an .ipa file (My app). when I trying to install it form iTunes to my device, it is stuck on installing: like below screen and it's installing in my ipad but not installing iphone

in my iphone 75% it's installing then app is disappearing why this problem is coming please suugest me some one

[image]